# How do I retrieve the coordinates used to create an iOS MapKit MKPolygonView?

Tags: ios, iphone, mapkit, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am using apple mapkit to create 3 mkpolygonviews on a map using an nsarray.

What i need is to have a tap gesture recognizer to get the coordinates from each polygon.
Is this possible? if so, some sample code would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have reference to the `MKPolygon` objects (either your own reference or the `overlays` collection of the `MKMapView` object). And `MKPolygon` is `MKMultiPoint` subclass, which provides `points`, `pointsCount` and `getCoordinates` methods.

For example, if you use `getCoordinates`, you get and array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, which you can then use `convertCoordinate:toPointToView:` to convert that to a `CGPoint` that you can reference in gesture recognizer.